# Excel VBA - For Each - In & Vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use both the ForEach and Vlookup in my code. The results are giving me a run-time error 424: Object Required message. See the code below:

```
Sub LookupAndSort()
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("B6", Range("b7").End(xlToRight).Offset(-1, 0))
    cell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
        cell.Value.Offset(1, 0), Worksheets("Ref2").Range("A:C"), 3, False)
Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `cell.Value.Offset(1, 0)` to `cell.Offset(1, 0).Value`

`Offset` is a method of the `Range` object so you have to apply it to the cell and not to the cell's value

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Sub LookupAndSort()

Dim AllCells As Range
Dim AllCellsRange As Range

Set AllCellsRange = Range("B6", Range("b7").End(xlToRight).Offset(-1, 0))

For Each AllCells In AllCellsRange
    AllCells.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
    AllCells.Value.Offset(1, 0), Worksheets("Ref2").Range("A:C"), 3, False)
Next AllCells
End Sub
```

This I haven't tested, so let me know if it works out for you